# Magento stops working occasionally

Tags: magento

Sometimes Magento stops working and when i check var/report/ get this:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:59:"Mage registry key "_singleton/core/resource" already exists";i:1;s:868:"#0 /home/siteName/public_html/app/Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /home/siteName/public_html/app/Mage.php(477): Mage::register('_singleton/core...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource))
#2 /home/siteName/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(141): Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')
#3 /home/siteName/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(234): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->__construct('core_setup')
#4 /home/siteName/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /home/siteName/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /home/siteName/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /home/siteName/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:18:"/app/etc/local.xml";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Website works and this thing occurs several times a day. What could be the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mage registry key "\_singleton/core/resource" already exists in magento](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793897/mage-registry-key-singleton-core-resource-already-exists-in-magento)

Comment: I tried it just before you write. I still do not know whether it works. Tomorrow I will see how it will behave site

Comment: Before sometime I also got same error. so I investigate what's the matter behind that and I found that this issue occur while server was down. In my case this was the issue.... For more information you can refer below link. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/50025/mage-registry-key-singleton-admin-session-already-exists

Comment: It's fixed. Cache is the problem. Thank you!